# Need Help regarding android and c# .net app

Tags: c#, android

I am developing a taxi cab management system for final year project. The headquarter and taxi stands will use C# .net application which will be web based. On the other hand its an android App that is for taxi drivers displaying them maps.

1. I want to link both applications in a way that web based app can check the current position of drivers at runtime using maps.
2. If anyone calls taxi stand they designate the closest driver to them by sending a notification from web based app built on c# .net.

I am having trouble in that and I need guidance to start my project. I wanna know how can this be done.

Any suggestions to add new and interesting features would be more then welcome

In this project i have decided to use an algo which will automaticaly tell the admin staff where cab stands should be and where should i allocate more taxis.

Comment: You can use Google cloud Messaging to send a notification from the C# .Net application

Comment: how abouot refusing the project and start your own bussines with the idea, obviously they cannt, but they let you build their product. your a student let them pay you a year income first. i think its terribly bad companies let scholars do their job, to get rich on it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has spent a lot of time building the tools you need to do exactly what you are wanting to do.

**First)** You would have some kind of database that housed:

Current Taxi Location
Pickup Requests
Other Business Information

**Second)** You would then have an Azure Worker Role which would:

1. Listen For Messages (more on this below).
2. Handle logic of which taxi gets the pickup request
3. Send Messages to taxi and dispatch (more on this below)

**Third)** You would setup a Service Bus for sending and receiving messages.
You can also implement a Service Bus Notification hub that will send a message to an android device when a message is sent from the web app.

See: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-notification-hubs/

[image]
Use Case:

Taxi drivers are constantly sending messages over the service bus with their current location.  Worker role is storing this data.

I call for a taxi.  Dispatch puts in my location of pickup into Web Interface.

Web interface sends a message over service bus with my requested pickup location, time, etc.

Worker role gets that message. Worker role looks in the data in the databse and determines Taxi 3 is available and near by.  Worker role then sends a push message to that taxis Android device about my location and needing a pickup.  Taxi driver can response saying accepted.

you get the point.

Comment: Yes you got my point totally and thanks for a brief answer, i thought no body replied becuase i didnt get any email.

Comment: Now getting to the point.. i am currently designing database and i wanna know is sql good or mySql will suite this type of app.. i have transfered the mobile app from android to hybrid app and yea i wanna know what is azure? The worker role? I got your point but i am not an expert. I am assuming worker role as an db table with logics and apps linked to this single db by sum algos

Comment: Azure is microsoft's cloud platform.  Instead of running your own servers, you pay as you go to use theirs.  It also has neat things like the ability to push to mobile devices, which is hard to do.

A worker role is basically a virtual machine that is running tasks.   As far a database, I'm sure mySQL would work just as well as any other flavor of SQL out there. 

Don't feel locked into the Microsoft architecture though!  You could use RabitMQ or some other messaging system.  The basic point is that you want a system that can receive JSON/XML messages and deal with them!

Answer (score 0):

Use SOAP to communicate both apps on the network
Then you are able to transfer everything by simple variables

Comment: I wish SOAP would go to bed already... I'd personally setup a Service Bus with a subscription service and send a common XML object with the data you need.  You could even use Azure to push messages to the android using Azure mobile services.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will consider using azure then soap